# How to change port for Yii2 micro framework

Tags: yii2

want to change port number for Yii2 micro framework

https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/tutorial-yii-as-micro-framework

this is commont to up a Yii2 micro server

```
vendor/bin/yii serve --docroot=./web
```

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the address with port as argument of `serve` command.

For example like this:

```
vendor/bin/yii serve localhost:8088 --docroot=./web
```

Answer (score 1):

just simply open your CMD and type this command

```
php yii serve --port 3030
```

`3030` is your port which you want